# automatic resize using qgraphicsview with qgraphicsscene and qopenglwidget

Tags: qt, opengl, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to use QGraphicsView with QOpenGLWidget in a MainWindow:
Exactly:
My QMainWindow contains a few layouts and widget. Also a QGraphicsView (class graphicsView inherits from QGraphicsView).

In a "second" step i create a QGraphicsScene and add a openglwidget (class OpenGLControl inherits from QOpenGLWidget). In OpenGLControl I only set the backround for testing my application (glClearColor ...).

Now my request, when I change the size of mainWindow, i want to change the size of QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QOpenGLWidget, too. I try a resizeEvent in graphicsView, but it didn't work.

Implementation of mainwindow (.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "openglcontrol.h"
#include "graphicsview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
                 : QMainWindow(parent)
{
createLayout();
createScene();

}

void MainWindow::createLayout()
{
view = new graphicsView;
kosGrid = new QGridLayout;
xKoord = new QLineEdit;
yKoord = new QLineEdit;
zKoord = new QLineEdit;
drawButton = new QPushButton("Draw Point");
clearButton = new QPushButton("Clear");
KoordLabel = new QLabel("Koordinaten");
xLabel = new QLabel("X:");
yLabel = new QLabel("Y: ");
zLabel = new QLabel("Z: ");
controlBox = new QVBoxLayout;

controlBox->addStretch(1);
controlBox->addWidget(KoordLabel);
xhBox = new QHBoxLayout;
xhBox->addWidget(xLabel);
xhBox->addWidget(xKoord);
controlBox->addLayout(xhBox);

yhBox = new QHBoxLayout;
yhBox->addWidget(yLabel);
yhBox->addWidget(yKoord);
controlBox->addLayout(yhBox);

zhBox = new QHBoxLayout;
zhBox->addWidget(zLabel);
zhBox->addWidget(zKoord);
controlBox->addLayout(zhBox);

controlBox->addWidget(drawButton);
controlBox->addWidget(clearButton);
xKoord->setFixedWidth(50);
yKoord->setFixedWidth(50);
zKoord->setFixedWidth(50);
drawButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);

xKoord->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
yKoord->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
zKoord->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);

hBox = new QHBoxLayout;
hBox->addLayout(controlBox);
hBox->addWidget(view);

mainLayout = new QWidget;
mainLayout->setLayout(hBox);

setCentralWidget(mainLayout);
}

void MainWindow::createScene()
{
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

qsurface = new QSurfaceFormat;
qsurface->setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
qsurface->setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
qsurface->setVersion(3,3);

oglwidget = new OpenGLControl;
oglwidget->setFormat(*qsurface);
oglwidget->
//oglwidget->resize(10,10);

scene->addWidget(oglwidget);

view->setScene(scene);
}
```

and my attempt for the resizeEvent:

```
void graphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
if(scene())
    scene()->setSceneRect(QRect(QPoint(0,0), event->size()));
QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

at last a screenshot of the (resized) mainWindow (the QOpenGLWidget (blue background) is smaller than the QGraphicsView)
[mainWindow with QOpenGLWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thPtu.png)

Is there a SIGNAL I can use ? Or can anybody help me on another way ?
Thank You

Comment: If you consider that `QGraphicsScene` is a world in which objects (`QGraphicsItems` & `QGraphicsObjects`) reside and `QGraphicsView` is a window into that world, why are you trying to resize the scene? This doesn't logically make sense.

Comment: I solved the problem: on the one hand I add to graphicsView sizeChanged event a Signal to change of the OpenGLWidget. On the other The size of the GraphicsScene grows with the GraphicsView, but does never shrink. So I need a signal in de graphicsView sizeChanged event for the szene, too.